# How to stop bubble sort when top n values are found?

Tags: java, sorting

I am currently learning Java and I have a question to ask about bubble sort.

Let's say I have an array of numbers called array and I sort it using bubble sort.

```java
int[] array = {10, 22, 30, 50, 11, 22, 80, 66, 55, 32};

        for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length - 1 -i; j++) {
                  if (array[j + 1] < array[j]) {
                    int temp;
                    temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
```

My goal is to find the largest n values of the list and **stop the sorting once n largest values are found**. If variable b is the number of times it takes a value to compare. How does n relate to b?

In this particular case, if n = 3 then it should stop where the arrow is.
During each step, the output is:

```
[10, 22, 30, 50, 11, 22, 80, 66, 55, 32]
[10, 22, 30, 50, 11, 22, 80, 66, 55, 32]
[10, 22, 30, 50, 11, 22, 80, 66, 55, 32]
[10, 22, 30, 11, 50, 22, 80, 66, 55, 32]
[10, 22, 30, 11, 22, 50, 80, 66, 55, 32]
[10, 22, 30, 11, 22, 50, 80, 66, 55, 32]
[10, 22, 30, 11, 22, 50, 66, 80, 55, 32]
[10, 22, 30, 11, 22, 50, 66, 55, 80, 32]
[10, 22, 30, 11, 22, 50, 66, 55, 32, 80]
[10, 22, 30, 11, 22, 50, 66, 55, 32, 80]
[10, 22, 30, 11, 22, 50, 66, 55, 32, 80]
[10, 22, 11, 30, 22, 50, 66, 55, 32, 80]
[10, 22, 11, 22, 30, 50, 66, 55, 32, 80]
[10, 22, 11, 22, 30, 50, 66, 55, 32, 80]
[10, 22, 11, 22, 30, 50, 66, 55, 32, 80]
[10, 22, 11, 22, 30, 50, 55, 66, 32, 80]
[10, 22, 11, 22, 30, 50, 55, 32, 66, 80]
[10, 22, 11, 22, 30, 50, 55, 32, 66, 80]
[10, 22, 11, 22, 30, 50, 55, 32, 66, 80]
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 50, 55, 32, 66, 80]
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 50, 55, 32, 66, 80]
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 50, 55, 32, 66, 80]
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 50, 55, 32, 66, 80]
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 50, 55, 32, 66, 80]
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 50, 32, 55, 66, 80] <--- where the sorting should stop ( 3 largest value found )
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 50, 32, 55, 66, 80]
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 50, 32, 55, 66, 80]
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 50, 32, 55, 66, 80]
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 50, 32, 55, 66, 80]
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 50, 32, 55, 66, 80]
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 50, 32, 55, 66, 80]
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 50, 32, 55, 66, 80]
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 32, 50, 55, 66, 80]
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 32, 50, 55, 66, 80]
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 32, 50, 55, 66, 80]
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 32, 50, 55, 66, 80]
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 32, 50, 55, 66, 80]
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 32, 50, 55, 66, 80]
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 32, 50, 55, 66, 80]
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 32, 50, 55, 66, 80]
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 32, 50, 55, 66, 80]
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 32, 50, 55, 66, 80]
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 32, 50, 55, 66, 80]
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 32, 50, 55, 66, 80]
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 32, 50, 55, 66, 80]
[10, 11, 22, 22, 30, 32, 50, 55, 66, 80]
```

Answer (score 0):

[In bubble sort:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Optimizing_bubble_sort)

> n-th pass finds the n-th largest element and puts it into its final
>   place

So in your code, if you want to want to find the largest n items, you should set **b** equal to **n**. When the outer loop quits, the last n items in the array will be the n largest values.

*Edit (in response to comment):*

The word **pass** in the above definition refers to the number of times the outer loop runs. Without having information about the array it is hard to determine the exact number of iterations of the inner loop. Take the following example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This is alreayd sorted. If `b = 2`, then after two **passes**, it is guaranteed that the last two elements are the largest (3 and 4). But the program does not even enter the inner loop. Now if this is the array:

```
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

again after two passes, we will have:

```
[2, 1, 3, 4]
```

The difference is, the inner loop iterated 3 times and 2 times respectively to put 3 and 4 at tail of the array. For a completely reverse sorted array, the inner loop will do total:

```
(n - 1) + (n - 2) + ... + 1
```

iterations.

Comment: Although the one you mentioned is not the most efficient way to find the largest n using bubble sort since more than the required steps are still taken.
I added some clarification to my question. Please have a look.

Comment: @User2524 I edited the answer. Please see if this answers the question.